# Future of the commands used by pdfTeX, pdfLaTeX and related engines making use of the pdf-extension

Tags: pdftex, best-practices

I'm currently in the process of building a class file with preferrably a best practice setup of the macros. My current paradigm is to write all macros in (plain) TeX, since I find it contradictory to call dependencies on packages (be it stable releases or not) best practice.

Starting with the assumption that this is correct, I *am* willing to make use of the extensions provided by the `pdf` part of `pdfTeX` and `pdfLaTeX` (think the `\pdfliteral{}` command for colouring or what have you). First I'd like to know however what exactly I can expect of these commands. I really wish to use only stable macros in my class file so that this can be used in the distant future by anyone who so desires.

To phrase the question more concisely: **Can I expect a change to the `\pdf`-related commands or can I consider them *completely* stable so that it compiles in the same way twenty years from now?**

Comment: I think you get better answers when you ask this on the [pdfTeX mailing list](https://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/pdftex).

Comment: When you say "Plain TeX", do you mean the TeX "primitives" (such as `\long`, `\outer`, `\expandafter`, `\noexpland`, and `\relax`), or the set of macros (described in the TeXbook) that build on the primitives to make TeX usable by humans? While it's true that by not relying on previously written package code you don't make yourself vulnerable to issues that may arise if the packages are ever changed significantly in the future, it's also the case that packages that have been around for a long time are probably thoroughly debugged by now. Why not make use of their embedded accumulated wisdom?

Comment: If Adobe decides that is `q` is no more fashionable, then every `\pdfliteral{q ...}` will become unusable. Not that I expect this, but it's an example of what can go wrong when something depends on third party software.

Comment: You don't say quite what you want to achieve, but for example `\pdfliteral` is really required to do some low-level stuff with pdfTeX as it's more-or-less part of the driver interface. What do you plan to do about working with other drivers (`dvips`, `xdvipdfmx`, _etc._)?

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you for your answer. I intend to leave the options open to make the output as device independent as possible. I'm not sure yet how I wish to achieve this but I'll first have to investigate the `pdf` extensions to understand what I'm doing.

Comment: @Mico Plain TeX is by definition the extension laid out in the TeX book, while TeX is the set of primitives from which you mentioned several.

Comment: @1010011010 Driver-independence is easy enough: you need a 'layer' approach as seen in `graphics` or `pgf` with higher-level commands independent of the driver an lower-level ones tied to the driver. You then just need a selection mechanism to pick the appropriate code.

Comment: @JosephWright Are you referring to logic trees and conditional statements?

Comment: @1010011010 No idea what you mean about trees! Probably one for chat in any case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted in a comment, an *ex cathedra* answer here really can only come on the pdfTeX mailing list, but hopefully we can at least examine the likely factors involved.

As development effort has moved from pdfTeX to LuaTeX, changes to pdfTeX beyond strict bug fixes seems very unlikely. Indeed, the efforts made in developing pdfTeX have had a strong sense of maintaining stability, which is why both TeX Live and MiKTeX have been prepared to use pdfTeX as the default engine for everything except `tex` (which will always use an unmodified version of Knuth's TeX).

If you look at the primitives provided by pdfTeX beyond those provided by Knuth's TeX90, the most 'stable' set are the e-TeX extensions, finalised in 1999 and unchanged since (barring bug-fixes). Those prefixes `\pdf...` may be examined by the version of pdfTeX which first introduced them: those available for longer are more likely to be widely used and thus 'stable' by virtue of the fact that removal would be a significant issue. That said, there has not been a major release of pdfTeX for some years and even then *removal* of  primitives has been very carefully handled (a deprecation phase before withdrawal meaning that several years notice have been available).

If one looks specifically at `\pdfliteral`, it is equivalent to `\special{pdf: ...}` and is thus directly linked to the PDF mode driver implemented by pdfTeX. It is thus directly linked to the 'core' ability of pdfTeX and so can be regarded as as stable as anything else.

---

All of this is of course coloured by what we can interpret as 'stability'. Even Knuth's TeX can still change in the sense of bug fixes, and while these are now extremely rare any change at all in the sources may have a knock-on on one or more use cases. Looking at anything more complex, using TeX in the future depends on the continued availability of TeX systems, the appropriate binaries and so on.

---

Perhaps worth noting here is that the question seems to focus on developing LaTeX2e classes or packages. (Classes should primarily be about design, so I will assume that the 'programming' element here is in a package.) It thus relies on the fact that LaTeX2e itself will be stable enough that no changes are required to keep files entirely unchanged for that reason. The LaTeX team have been careful to try to provide a system which seeks to do this, but there are bugs in LaTeX and fixing them does mean some changes over time.

What I would note in the LaTeX team context is that for work on `expl3`/LaTeX3 (where the team want to have a 'stable' underlying basis) the use of a small number of `\pdf...` primitives has been regarded as sensible. When using pdfTeX, string comparisons use `\pdfstrcmp` while  scalings and rotations exploit `\pdfliteral`. Graphics inclusion is not written for this but we might assume that `\pdfximage` and so forth will be used.

Comment: I'll accept your answer ás soon as I have additional information from the mailing list (for answer completeness). Or maybe authority can provide insight in another answer.